# How to attach an Event Handler for dynamically generated Child divs?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I have a page with 2 Div containers ( Left and Right ). 
PartsList page has 5 dynamically generated DIVS.
Custom page has 5 dynamically generated DIVS.
The div with id "layout" isnt getting recognized with the jQuery .on(). Please help. Thank you for you time :).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $(".left").load("PartsList.php",function() {alert("success");});

    $(".right").load("Custom.php", function() {alert("success");});

        $("#layout").children().on({click: function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));

          }
 });    

});
</script>

<body>
<div class="main">

<div class="left">
//Load Left page.

</div>
<div class="right">

//Load Structure page.
</div>

</div>
</body>


</html>
```

PartsList

```
<?php


for ($x = 1; $x < 6; $x++)
{

   $divs = <<<here
   <div id = 'div$x' class = 'list'><strong>Div: $x</strong></div>
   here;
   echo $divs;
 }

?>
```

Custom

```
<?php

echo '<div id="layout">';

for ($y = 0; $y < 5; $y++)
{
        echo "<div id='x$y' style='
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        top: ".(100 * $y)."px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        cursor: pointer;
        '></div>";
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: After testing for a while. I found out that the pages are getting loaded after the #layout instruction. Anybody know why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jquery 1.7+ use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```
$(document).on('click','dynamicElement',function(e){

 //handler code here
});
```

in the earlier versions use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate('dynamicElement','click',function(e){

 //handler code here
});
```

you can replace the `document` with parent element of the dynamically generated element

Comment: The method isnt working. Could you please provide me a working example with my piece of code. It would be really helpful. Thank You :)

Comment: Your answer was right :). Sorry about the Quotes though <.<!~

Answer (score 1):

From the Jquery online manual:

.load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )

url: string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

data: map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

**complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)A callback function that is executed when the request completes.**

You probably need to put the .on function as a callback of the .load for that Custom.php page.

Something like this EXAMPLE:

```
$(function() {

    $(".left").load("PartsList.php",function() {alert("success");});

    $(".right").load("Custom.php", function() {alert("success");

        $("#layout").children().on({click: function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));

          }
 });
 });    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the wrong syntax for the .on() function it should be something like:

```
$('document').on('click', '#layout > div', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You bind to the document and when a user clicks on a child div in layout the event 'bubbles' up the DOM to the document where it is caught.

Comment: I tried your method but it isnt working either. For some reason when i use firebug and test the commands in the console, it works. But on the page it acts as if the element never existed.

Comment: everyone who even thinks of using `$(this).attr('id')`, should receive a prophylactic kicking .. and same goes for use of `alert()` as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found the answer anyhow. For people who were thinking why it didnt work. It was because of the stupid QUOTES.

$("document") should have been $(document) since document isnt a tag <.

And tada thats it.

Sigh.

Thanks for the help everyone :)