# Instructions arent following the sequence jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the code that i have been working on. Apparently the #layout call is executed first for some reason and it gives undefined as the value.

```
$(function() {

    $(".left").load("PartsList.php", function() {
        alert("success");
    });

    $(".right").load("Custom.php", function() {
        alert("success");
    });

    $("#layout").children().on({
        click: function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));

        }
    });

});​
```

Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `.load()` is called asynchronously.

You may bind with

```
$("#layout").on({
    click: function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

    }
}, '.left,.right');
```

instead

Comment: Here is the test code. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776995/how-to-attach-an-event-handler-for-dynamically-generated-child-divs

Comment: @LearningSlowly: replace `$("#layout")` with `$(document)`. http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/cSz3G/

Comment: Replaced it with $(document) still not working. Thank you for sharing your time :)

Comment: @LearningSlowly: now it is a good time to start doing something rather than copy-paste. Have you looked at my jsfiddle? Did you understand how it works?

Comment: Yep it works :). Sorry for my mistake. I kept using double quotes in $(document). That was the problem :).